# PHP: unable to find the socket transport "socks"

Tags: php, composer-php, lamp

I'm trying to install Laravel but as i enter this command:

`composer global require "laravel/installer"`,

i get this:

> file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "socks" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

even i had this error trying to install composer so i had to download it from Github.
I tried to uncomment the `;extension=php_openssl.dll` in php.ini file but there was no such thing in it.
any solution? (using Linux fedora - Apache 2.4.33)

Comment: check your php.ini has `allow_url_fopen` on ?

Comment: this may solve your problem https://rewgaz.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/enable-remote-fsockopen-in-php-von-fedora-selinux/

Comment: @rkj yes, it's "on".

Comment: @rkj no it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not installed all Php extension.Try to install all php required extension than install laravel.Try the command `yum install php-mysql php-pdo php-xml php-mcrypt php-mbstring php-gd` after that restart your webserver than install laravel.

Comment: which web server you are using?

Comment: using Apache 2.4.33